# How to add a attribute only to a specific patch out of all patches?

Tags: netlogo, agent

I want a slider based input as an attribute in a specific patch only. For example, I am trying to model the horse [agent] selecting only good quality grass. As an input as patches, I have patches with grasses, crops, barren land etc. The main focus here is the grass patch. It already has a variable high (3), medium (2) and low-quality grass (1). So I wanted to add an attribute to the grass patch only (only grass, this is important) which can be controlled by a slider during the setup (setting up the environment) to experiment.

I tried this code but it does not work (and gives me a java heap error)

```
set fodder gis:load-dataset "Data/grass.asc"
 gis:apply-raster fodder grass
 ask patches [if grass = 3 [set pcolor green]                  
              if grass = 2 [set pcolor yellow]                    
              if grass = 1 [set pcolor red]                       ;; 1 is low quality 
  ]
if any? patches with [grass <= 3] [ask patches [set modified-grass quality-of-grass]]  ;; controlled by slider
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of possible problems here.  First, I assume that `grass` is a `patches-own` variable.  I've not worked with the gis extension, but I assume that it is setting the value of `grass` to 1, 2 or 3 for certain of the patches that are to be grass patches. The value of `grass` for all patches is initialized to zero, so non-grass patches will have `grass` equal to zero.  Therefore, when you use the expression `patches with [grass <= 3]` you are referring not to just grass patches, but to all patches.  (Of course you may have set `grass` to some value greater than 3 for non-grass patches, in which case this is not a problem.)

Second, you said that you wanted to set `modified-grass` (another `patches-own` variable?) to the slider value only for grass patches.  But `[ask patches [set modified-grass quality-of-grass]]` sets the `grass` variable for **all** patches, not just grass patches.

So, I think that what you might really want here is

```
ask patches with [grass > 0 and grass <= 3] [set modified-grass quality-of-grass]
```

If there are no such patches, nothing will happen.

Now I don't know why either of these issues would lead to a java heap error. Are you sure that is not happening earlier in your code?

Comment: Thank you Charles, I think your suggestion revealed the problem. The code works now. I also increased the memory ceiling of the Netlogo which also I guess solved the issue of java heap space error.

Comment: You may also consider putting your patches of various kinds in collections. Like set grasses patches with [grass > 0 and grass <= 3]  ... then you can “ask grasses [ do-stuff] which may speed up your code and may improve the clarity of the code. This assumes that grass patches stay grass patches.